# Unable to debug angular e2e tests with Protractor in VS-Code

Tags: protractor

I am unable to run my angular e2e test in debug mode. browser.debug() is not working.

Node Version - 10.13.0
Angular 8 
protractor - 5.4.2

Here is a sample of my launch.json file of vs code.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ng e2e",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/e2e/protractor.conf.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Error Log ::

```
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

[Error log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzQsd.png)

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I have disabled the control flow and using async await. Getting an exception in q.js.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `browser.debug()` method, it's not working with disabled control flow.

You have two options:

1. Add `debugger` keyword to the test case that you want to debug.

   ```
   it('should greet the named user', async function() {
     debugger;
     await browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

     await element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');

     var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

     expect(await greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');

   });
   ```
2. Add a breakpoint in the [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

   [image]

Then press `F5` or `Ctrl+F5` buttons to run tests.

Here is my `launch.json` file that works:

```
   {
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
     {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Run",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
     },
     ]
   }
```

Comment: I have opted the 2nd option. But is not working. Giving an exception in node_modules/q.js

Comment: Try to add `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to the `launch.json` file.  Updated answer.

Comment: Tried but still giving the exception in q.js. Can't understand why this is happening